# Script in Unix to Remove XML tags and contents from file

Tags: xml, shell, unix, awk, sed

Basically need to remove the parties entity (and everything in between) from a set of individual XML files named by number.xml. I tried the following but it's not quite producing everything I need:

```
    cat test.xml | sed "s;<parties>;\do_opentag ;" | sed "s;</parties>;\do_closetag ;" |  awk 'BEGIN { doPrint = 1; } /do_opentag/ { doPrint = 0; print $0; } /do_closetag/ { doPrint = 1; } { if (doPrint) print $0; }' | grep -v 'do_opentag\|do_closetag'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" pid="58326519" doc-generation-date="2016-10-11">
  <bibliographic-data>
    <application-reference>
      <pan>46422</pan>
    </application-reference>
    <publication-reference>
      <publication-office>KR</publication-office>
      <patent-publication-date>
        <year>2016</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <day>11</day>
      </patent-publication-date>
    </publication-reference>
    <parties>
      <applicants>
        <applicant sequence="1">
          <name lang="EN"></name>
          <address>
            <location-of-work>KR</location-of-work>M
          </address>
        </applicant>
      </applicants>
    </parties>
  </bibliographic-data>
  <vendor>Any</vendor>
  <document-translation-date>2016-11-24</document-translation-date>M
  <invention-title lang="EN">Cell preservation container for liquid-based cell inspection</invention-title>
  <abstract lang="EN">The present invention relates to a liquid for discharging liquid containing cells and cell may be a sampling which is simply eminent generated in </abstract>
  <comment lang="EN"></comment>
</patent-document>
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing XML *requires* an XML parser. [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) is fairly simple to use. To delete the `parties` node:

```
xmlstarlet ed -P -d '//parties' file.xml
```

producing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" pid="58326519" doc-generation-date="2016-10-11">
  <bibliographic-data>
    <application-reference>
      <pan>46422</pan>
    </application-reference>
    <publication-reference>
      <publication-office>KR</publication-office>
      <patent-publication-date>
        <year>2016</year>
        <month>10</month>
        <day>11</day>
      </patent-publication-date>
    </publication-reference>

  </bibliographic-data>
  <vendor>Any</vendor>
  <document-translation-date>2016-11-24</document-translation-date>M
  <invention-title lang="EN">Cell preservation container for liquid-based cell inspection</invention-title>
  <abstract lang="EN">The present invention relates to a liquid for discharging liquid containing cells and cell may be a sampling which is simply eminent generated in </abstract>
  <comment lang="EN"/>
</patent-document>
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e '/<parties>/,/<\/parties>/d' test.xml`

In sed you can use two patterns separated by a comma to apply a sed command or commands to the range of lines including and between the matching patterns.   Here I am saying `d`-- delete the line-- from `/<parties>/` to `/<\/parties>/`.

This is dependent on the formatting of your XML.  There can be no other content on the matching lines that you would need to retain.

If you want to edit the file in place, add a `-i` flag to sed.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. For some reason, I'm getting a message saying "missing newline at end of file test.xml" and the closing </patent-document> tag is getting dropped. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Because the last line doesn't contain a terminating newline character, sed's never processing it.   I've never seen this issue, but [the second answer here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file) seems reasonable:  `echo >> test.xml; sed -e '/<parties>/,/<\/parties>/d' test.xml`